# Need help constructing If statement in Excel

Tags: excel-formula

I have an Excel document which consists of two sheets.

Hey I have an Excel doc where one sheet consists of this one statement which is in one cell.

"When(ASecurityID is "x") {set field BSecurityID toValue "y")

In sheet two I have list of ASecurityIDs in one column. And in the other column I have a list of BsecurityIDs.

Now for each row I want to create a "When(ASecurityID is "x") {set field BSecurityID toValue "y") statement and I want the IDs to appear in the "x" and "y" part of the statement.

Can somebody guide me as to how I would construct the If statement?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding your question correctly, you would put in Sheet 1, Cell A1:

```
="When(ASecurityID is "&Sheet2!A1&") {set field BSecurityID toValue"&Sheet2!B1&")"
```

I'm assuming you don't need quotation marks in your output. If you do, I would add them by using the ascii value, it's a lot less confusing:

```
... &CHAR(34)&Sheet2!A1&CHAR(34)& ...
```